# PHP not looping through data

Tags: php

Why is this file not looping through the data? It's only showing the last (or 'most recent') record only. [it should be painfully obvious that I'm new to PHP]

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<br />
<a href="add.php">Add entry</a><br>
<br>

<?php

include("connect.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qual");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num > 0 ) { $i=0;
 while ($i < $num) {

         $id = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"id"));
     $field1 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field1"));
     $field2 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field2"));
     $field3 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field3"));
     $field4 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field4"));
     $field5 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field5"));
     $field6 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field6"));
     $field7 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field7"));
     $field8 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field8"));
     $field9 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field9"));
     $field9 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field9"));
    $field10 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field10"));
    $field11 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field11"));
    $field12 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field12"));
    $field13 = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"field13"));

    $row = '<tr>
                <td>'.$num.'</td>
                <td>'.$field1.'</td>
                <td>'.$field2.'</td>
                <td>'.$field3.'</td>
                <td>'.$field4.'</td>
                <td>'.$field5.'</td>
                <td>'.$field6.'</td>
                <td>'.$field7.'</td>
                <td>'.$field8.'</td>
                <td>'.$field9.'</td>
                <td>'.$field9.'</td>
                <td>'.$field10.'</td>
                <td>'.$field11.'</td>
                <td>'.$field12.'</td>
                <td>'.$field13.'</td>
                <td><a href="update.php?id='.$id.'">Update</a></td>
                <td><a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';

++$i; }} else
{ $row = '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Nothing found</td></tr>'; }

mysql_close();
?>

<table width="150%" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>field1</td>
            <td>field2</td>
            <td>field3</td>
            <td>field4</td>
            <td>field5</td>
            <td>field6</td>
            <td>field7</td>
            <td>field8</td>
            <td>field9</td>
            <td>field10</td>
            <td>field11</td>
            <td>field12</td>
            <td>field13</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>

<?php echo $row ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You could take at look at PDO or MYSQLi becaus MYSQL library for php is deprecated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `if` condition line, initialize the `$row = "";`.

You have to concatenate the rows in both `if` and `else` case

not `$row = '<tr>`

I should be

```
$row .= '<tr>
```

Comment: When I do this, it says the row variable is undefined and references the line with the end TR -- `<tr>';`

Comment: what is the error message you gettng exactly?

Comment: `PHP Notice: Undefined variable: row in <path><filename> on line 59`

Comment: then do `$row = '';` before `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

A. You should never need to run `stripslashes` on a DB result, that means you inserted the data wrong.

B. You should switch to MySQLi/PDO because [the original MySQL extension is now deprecated.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

C. You are creating a new `$row` each time and only echo it once, at the end.

D. Did you really name your fields `field1`-`field13`???

This could be written so much simpler. Here's a simple PDO version:

```
//Echo table header.

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM qual';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
   // echo the row contents now.
}
```

Comment: A. I am trying to modify code that was already written. Being new to all this, I didn't know about that 'stripslashes' issue. I just knew it didn't seem to be hurting anything by leaving it in there. 

B. I will look into that.

C. When I change the 'row =' to 'row .=' it tells me the row variable is undefined. 

D. No, I didn't name my variables that in my file. I just 'anonymized' the file.

Comment: You need to create `$row` once, and then add to it. Before the loop, have `$row = ''`;

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding `$row` on every iteration. Use `$row .= '<tr>...` inside the loop to concatinate the rows.

Answer (score 0):

starting from:

```
<?php

include("connect.php");
```

you can use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qual");
$toStamp = "";
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $id = stripslashes($row["id"]);
  $field1 = stripslashes($row["field1"]);
  //etc

  $toStamp = $toStamp.'<tr><td>'.$id.'</td> // Adding this line to the existing $row
            <td>'.$field1.'</td>
            //etc
 } else {
  $toStamp = '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Nothing found</td></tr>';
}
}
```

// Edited a little, removed some code error.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried displaying $num value before looping, to check there are really more than 1 result to your query?